# Required Field Validation Redirects to a New Blade in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application, I have I'm trying to add a new users via blade form.

Following is my store method in the controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)

    {
        $user_roleId = Auth::user()->role_id;

         try{

            $roleid = $request->input('roles');
        
            if(empty($roleid)){
                
               
                    $roleid='3';
               
            }
            else{

                $roleid=$request->input('roles');
        
                if($roleid=='Admin'){
                    $roleid='1';    
                }else if($roleid=='Regional Admin'){
                    $roleid='2'; 
                }else{
                    $roleid='3'; 
                }
            } 
    
            $request->merge(['role_id' => ''.$roleid.'']);
    
            $this->validate($request, [
    
                'first_name' => 'required',
    
                'last_name' => 'required',
    
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    
                'password' => 'required|same:confirm-password',
    
                'roles' => 'required',
    
                'image_id' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    
                'role_id'=>'required',
    
                'region_id'=>'required',

                'profile_type'=>'required',
    
                'gender'=>'required',

                'email_verified_at'=>'required',
    
                'date_of_birth'=>['required','date',  function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        
                    $age=Carbon::parse($value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
                    if($age<18||$age>45){
                        $fail('Âge invalide. l\'âge devrait être 18-45');
                    }
                   
                },]
    
    
            ]);
    
            $input = $request->all();
            
            if ($image = $request->file('image_id')) {
    
                $destinationPath = 'propics/';
    
                $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
                $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
    
                $input['image_id'] = $profileImage;
    
            }

            if($user_roleId=='1'){
    
                $input['region_id']= $input['region_id']+1;

            }
             

            $input['profile_type']= $input['profile_type']+1;
            
            $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
    
            $user = User::create($input);
    
            $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

            //$user->notify(new SendRegisterMailNotification());
    
            return redirect()->route('participants.index')
    
                            ->with('success',__('texts.Participant created successfully.'));

        }

        catch (Exception $e){

            return redirect()->route('participants.index')

            ->with('failed',__('texts.An error has been occured.'));
        }
         
    }
```

Now my issue is,

Even though I have this required validation, Once if a user hits the save button with empty fields, it redirects the user to `participants.index` blade, and there show an error, `" Sorry an error has been occurred"` .

But I want to display the field is required as an error message on the form itself (under the field) without redirecting to the index blade.

I have my form fields as follows in the blade (only one filed included here)

```
{!! Form::text('first_name', null, array('placeholder' => __('texts.first name'),'class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) !!}
                        {!! $errors->first('first_name', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}
```

I am expecting not to use HTML `required` attribute

Comment: I've updated the content

Comment: There are multiple issues/enhancements in this code. 1. Remove validation inside try-catch and move out. 2. you can use `$request->has('roles')` instead of `isset`. ...

Comment: [Did you check the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation)?  They are really quite good, with plenty of examples - and they show you should not try/catch validation exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have use a try catch it will redirect to index. Reason is validation get failed so it will catch that and then redirect to index.

**Remove try catch to fix redirect to index**

**Additional info**

Move your validation into a validation request. Don't put validation inside a method.Gahter more info about this refactoring via [The clean coder's guide to laravel](https://ashallendesign.co.uk/pdf/The-Clean-Coders-Guide-to-Laravel.pdf). Check page 2 - 8 there. You can have a clear idea about this with document.

For your issue this answer well [Laravel Validation](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-validation-101-controllers-form-requests-and-rules)

Comment: well this has given me the following error, TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given

Comment: please remove the try catch.I have updated the answer. Actually you dont need to check validator fails . It automatically happens there

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Link you specified under **Laravel Validation**, is Form validation that uses **Rules method**, which is completely different from the question asked.

Comment: Yes @AbdullaNilam you are  100% correct. Thats why I put it below additional info for more references

Answer (score 0):

```
$rules = [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        ];
    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules, []);
    if ($validation->fails()) {
        $messages = $validation->errors();
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($messages);
    }
```

and In Html

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}">
   {!! Form::text('first_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control insertText','placeholder' => 'first name*']) !!}
   <span class="text-danger showError">{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

If validation fails then return redirect with error message and input.**Add validation field code before try-catch.**